# AJAX call using Angular Seed

Tags: angularjs, ajax, api, binding

*Edit:  James P. led me to determine that the issue appears to be with CORS and not necessarily with any of the Angular code.  Please read comments below.*

I am very new to AngularJS and JS altogether, so I'm sure the answer to this is something simple that I have overlooked so thank you in advance.

I am using Angular Seed and I have created an API that is verified working (as in, I go to my URL:3000/getstuff and it displays queries from my mongodb just fine).

That API returns a JSON format response from a mongodb with 3 key/pairs including id.  I am able to view it in browser just fine.

So in Angular seed, very basic view1/view1.js I modified to as such:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.view1', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/view1', {
    templateUrl: 'view1/view1.html',
    controller: 'View1Ctrl'
  });
}])

.controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  //$scope.test = "test";
  //the above works when I bind in view1.html

  $http.get('http://x.x.x.x:3000/getstuff').
  success(function(response) {
    $scope.information = response;
  });

}]);
```

And it is not working as I thought it might.  So when I try to bind this response in view1.html with a simple {{information}} it's blank.  This code did not break the app either, it still works and I am able to display {{test}} if I uncomment it.

Anyhow, any help would be very much appreciated.  And for the record, I have been reading up on this for days and days before posting this.  I am just a novice is all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) to copy the data to your `$scope` variable:

```
  $http.get('http://x.x.x.x:3000/getstuff')
            .then(function (response) {
                // Success
                angular.copy(response.data, $scope.information);
            }, function () {
                // Failure
        });
```

Then in your view:

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
   <div ng-repeat="item in information">
      <p>{{item.id}}</p>
      <p>{{item.type}}</p>
      <p>{{item.text}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where `id` ,`type` and `text` are properties of each item in the Array.

**EDIT**: Just for completeness the following is a working example, with above html snippet.

```
(function () {

"use strict";

angular.module("app", []);

angular.module("app").controller("MainController", mainController);

function mainController($scope, $http) {

    $scope.information = [];

    $http.get("http://api.scb.se/OV0104/v1/doris/en/ssd")
          .then(function (response) {
              // Success
              angular.copy(response.data, $scope.information);
          }, function () {
              // Failure
          });

}

})();
```

Comment: Hello James P.  Thanks a lot for trying to help me out.  I did add the angular.copy and same results, nothing is displaying.  In my view1.html should I try {{response.data.[key name]}} or just {{response}} or {{response.[key name]}}?  I have tried all ways, nothing worked yet.  But with your angular.copy suggestion it still isn't working, nothing is displaying from the API call. Edit:  I mean information.[key]

Comment: So I have plane Jane this: Collected at: {{information.datestamp}} (one of my json key/pairs is a timestamp).   My Express log IS showing that every time I reload the page the API is being hit.  So that narrows it down to something with the way I'm handling the data.  Is my problem that I am trying to store a 3 key/pair json call return as one variable?  Should it be an array instead? $scope.information {} ?  again.. please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: Yes it should be an array the you can just use `ng-repeat` to loop through the array - e.g. see above, will add to answer.

Comment: Dang.  Still getting all blanks on the view1.html page.  I am using:<div ng-repeat="item in information">
                <p>{{item.id}}</p>
                <p>{{item.datestamp}}</p>
                <p>{{item.top100}}</p>
            </div> and those are all of my keypairs.  I also tried ng-repeat with <li ng-repeat "items in formation">

Comment: Make sure you declare `$scope.information = [];` before the `$http.get`... - also are you getting any errors on console in F12 dev tools.

Comment: Just tried it with $scope.information = [];  and no dice.   I don't know what F12 dev tools are?  I am using Webstorm in windows and uploading to Github and then pulling onto my linux box on AWS EC2.

Comment: What browser are you using to display View1.html. In browser, e.g. Chrome hit F12 - and select the console tab. Copy/paste any errors.

Comment: Aaaah good call.  XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://x.x.x.x:3000/top100. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://x.x.x.x:8080' is therefore not allowed access. where x.x.x.x is my web server on AWS... I have 3000 and 8080 set as a security rule to allow.  I can see the API if I load it directly as page, it returns the appropriate JSON results from the mongodb.  Weird.  What could this mean?  Just googled it -- this is a whole new can of worms.  Yikes.

Comment: I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource  -- It's odd, because like I've said I can view the API by directly linking to it....